# undefined variable when using assignment operators(+=)

Tags: php, variables, undefined

i have trouble in `codeigneter` when using assignment operators (+=). Please help me.

Here my code in view:

```
<?php
$t = 220; 
$x += $t;

echo $x;
?>
```

i get the result but in my view there have a error mesage.

A PHP Error was encountered:

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: x

Comment: The `+=` operator is shorthand.  `$x += $t` is shorthand for `$x = $x + $t`.  As you can see, `$x` isn't defined, so you can't use it in the equation.

Comment: I will only point out the possibility to suppress the error with `@$x += $t;`. Encourage you not to do so.

Comment: Then why point it out @Laxus?

Answer (score 6):

`$x` is not initialized so just do this:

```
<?php

    $t = 220;
    $x = 0;

    $x += $t;

    echo $x;

?>
```

Output:

```
220
```

---

**Side Note:**

You can add error reporting at the top of your file to get error messages (ONLY in testing environment):

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: @user3238082 If you have a new question make a new one! So you get the full attention of every one :D Otherwise if you miss wrote you in your question you can edit it, and if it's changing large parts of the question mark it as an edit! Otherwise people will come by see the answers and the question and think that the answers are wrong because they don't match the question anymore!

Answer (score 1):

So define it:

```
<?php
    $x = 0;
    $t = 220; 
    $x += $t;    
    echo $x;
    ?>
```

You are telling the code to add to $x a number, this $x is not defined at that point.